# SQL Saving time in a different format (mm:ss,mmm)

Tags: php, mysql, time, sql-order-by

I have a table in my database and I want to fill it with times in a certain format. At the moment the type of the column is TIME and the format is hh:mm:ss.
However, I actually want to save time including miliseconds and using a different format. The format I want is: mm:ss,mmm (For example, 1:54,49).

I've already tried saving times using VARCHAR but (obviously) when I try to print those out to my website using ORDER BY in my query it will not work. Long story short, Can I save times in my database using a different format (Including miliseconds and commas)?

Comment: This may help [frac time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Like dpp days, it seems possible.  Don't have a reference for you though.  BTW, you should edit your question and add the tag 'database' (you can add up to 5 tags).

Answer (score 0):

You can already store the millisecond in mysql DATETIME o TIMESTAMP data type

> A DATETIME or TIMESTAMP value can include a trailing fractional
>   seconds part in up to microseconds (6 digits) precision. In
>   particular, any fractional part in a value inserted into a DATETIME or
>   TIMESTAMP column is stored rather than discarded. With the fractional
>   part included, the format for these values is 'YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS[.fraction]', the range for DATETIME values is '1000-01-01
>   00:00:00.000000' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999', and the range for
>   TIMESTAMP values is '1970-01-01 00:00:01.000000' to '2038-01-19
>   03:14:07.999999'. The fractional part should always be separated from
>   the rest of the time by a decimal point; no other fractional seconds
>   delimiter is recognized. For information about fractional seconds
>   support in MySQL, see Section 12.3.6, “Fractional Seconds in Time
>   Values”.

you can take a deep look a this doc http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html